# undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass in Ruby

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I am using RubyMine to create a website. I have a calculation I’m doing in the model that is no longer working. It has worked previously, but now I’m receiving a NoMethodError stating that there is an undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

I have multiple integers I’m adding in my “`roster.rb`” model, with the scope sorting as follows:

```
scope :sorted, -> { select('*, (passing_yards + passing_tds + qb_rushing + coaching_staff + age + physical_tools + intellect + surrounding_talent + health + consistency) as xoi').order('xoi DESC') }

def xoi
    passing_yards + passing_tds + qb_rushing + coaching_staff + age + physical_tools + intellect + surrounding_talent + health + consistency
  end
```

I have database entries using these integers that have worked just days ago, with the calculation working properly, and the numbers sorting accurately.

I can still define “xoi” with just one of these integers and the integer will show up properly. I can also define “xoi” with 2 + 2 and the answer will show up on my webpage properly as 4. But this calculation is no longer working.

The html page displaying the results of this calculation is as follows:

```
 <% @players.each do |player| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= player.xoi %></td>
          <td><%= player.last_name %></td>
          <td><%= player.first_name %></td>
          <td><%= player.pos %></td>
          <td><%= player.team %></td>
          <td><%= player.passing_yards %></td>
          <td><%= player.passing_tds %></td>
          <td><%= player.qb_rushing %></td>
          <td><%= player.coaching_staff %></td>
          <td><%= player.age %></td>
          <td><%= player.physical_tools %></td>
          <td><%= player.intellect %></td>
          <td><%= player.surrounding_talent %></td>
          <td><%= player.health %></td>
          <td><%= player.consistency %></td>
```

I must have made some small tweak that I can’t recover from. Version Control did not work for me.

It’s as though the “+” is just no longer working for this calculation (but I’m sure I’m just doing something wrong).

I’d appreciate any insight.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What are passing_yards and passing_tds?

Comment: Sorry...I didn't paste the entire section in.

Comment: I think a further question is why are you adding all of those things together? Some seem like strings and others like ints. And even if they are all the same type, that's a super long string/int, and you're putting all of the values into a table separately anyway.

Comment: That's a fair question, but all of them are actually integers. I have values from 1-10 for all of them, and the intent is to add them up

Comment: I have edited my question to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

*I don't understand why the method is undefined*

Here the method is defined. Check the below statement for error.

**undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass**

The problem is that

```
passing_yards
```

might be **nil** for that scenario. So while evaluating `def xoi`

```
passing_yards + passing_tds + qb_rushing + coaching_staff + age + physical_tools + intellect + surrounding_talent + health + consistency
```

it evaluates to

```
nil + passing_tds + ...
```

which is not allowed in ruby. Check the same in irb if you want.

```
> nil + 2
=> #<NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass>
>
```

Comment: No...this isn't it. If I put in each value on it's own (i.e. passing_yards all by itself or passing_tds all by itself)...it works fine. Somehow, it's just not adding them up. And this was working previously, so I don't know why it suddenly stopped.

Comment: It's as if it suddenly doesn't know what "+" means.

Comment: I'm sorry that you don't like his answer, but it's true.  Nothing forgot about plus.  Something is now nil that wasn't before, and you can't use + with nil.  nil is what doesn't know what "+" means.

Comment: It's not that I don't like the answer, it just doesn't solve anything for me. Your response makes sense, and it does make it sound like something else is now "nil"...but because I can get it to read each individual method, It's confusing to me why it can't add them all together. I'm sure I screwed something else up deeper than what I'm showing here. I do appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Did you check all the database entries for passing_yards? Are you sure there is no nil for atleast one entry?